# GridView.Databind() not working with object list

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, object, gridview

The problem I have is this: I have one GridView with a list objects as its data source, it binds with no problem. I have a DropDownList which have the event `SelectedIndexChanged`, and with this event, I add a new object to the list, after added I want to do a `GridView1.Databind()` so the new object appears in the GridView.

But this does not work, after I do `GridView1.Databind()` the data from the GridView gets lost. It even shows the `EmptyDataText`, but if I refresh the page, everything appears. Also, the DropDownList uses an object list as DataSource and was supposed to use `DropDownList1.Databind()` but it doesn't work too. It has the same data after the DataBinding, what I did to correct at least the DropDownList was to set the `DropDownList again manually.DataTextField = object.attribute1` and  `DropDownList.DataValueField = object.attribute2`. But with the GridView I'm stuck, can someone explain how the method `DataBind` works with a list of objects?

Comment: What are you binding GridView to?

Comment: To the list of objects, and it has no problem, it display all the data correctly the only problem is trying to refresh it

Comment: Can you post some of your code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To refresh a `asp:GridView` bound to a list set gridView.DataSource property first.

```
 gridView.DataSource = mylist;
 gridView.DataBind();
```

For non-database data it means that list itself must be preserved either in session variable or ViewState.

Comment: everytime I need to do `gridView.Databind()` I need to do this? I've did this in the `PageLoad()` already. Before using this list my system used MySqlDataSource, but now we are using ADO.net for security reasons and with MySqlDataSource you only needed to associate the DataSource of the GridView once. By the way, thanks for the answer with this it works.

Comment: I bet with MySqlDataSource you were using *DataSourceID* property. Which is, indeed, has to be assigned only once. DataSource, on the other hand is not persistable, each post back sets it back to null

Comment: That's it, thank you for the answer, just created a method called `GridView2Databind()` wich contain this two lines, since my code to create the object list come from a class e to call it I need to use `GridView2.DataSource = emit_bo.GetEmitenteTipo(Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.SelectedValue));`
I would be not easy to write all this everytime I need to do a Databind. Note that the code is a little complex because of one gridview depends on the other, didn't posted anything related to it because thought it would get harder to undestand.

Answer (score 0):

I remember having this issue a long time ago. I'm guessing the issue is that you don't have the GridView in an UpdatePanel.

If this is the case, the GridView won't refresh and show the changes right away. There's some trickiness about the dropdown placement (I think it has to be in the panel, as well), but I'm sure you can figure it out with some quick searches on UpdatePanel.

Comment: Thanks for the recomendation, didn't knew about this update panel, very useful, but didn't fixed it